# I have an Internal Server Error when I try to access in my Django site

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, server

I'm trying to push my portfolio in production with a server ubuntu 18.10 using apache2

The problem : 
I only access of the admin page and the home page of my site but when I try to acess in blog or projects like this www.mysite.com/blog or www.mysite.com/projects an "internal server error" displays

tree of my site bellow

```
___rp-portfolio
               |
               |___blog
               |
               |___media
               |
               |___personal_portfolio
               |                     |
               |                     |___wsgi.py, settings.py ...
               |
               |
               |___projects
               |
               |__static
               |
               |___venv
               |
               |___db.sqite3
               |
               |___manage.py
```

the .conf of the apache server bellow

```
Alias /static /home/username/rp-portfolio/static
  <Directory /home/username/rp-portfolio/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Alias /media /home/username/rp-portfolio/media
  <Directory /home/username/rp-portfolio/media>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /home/username/rp-portfolio/personal_portfolio>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/username/rp-portfolio/personal_portfolio/wsgi.py
  WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/username/rp-portfolio python-home=/home/username/rp-portfolio/venv
  WSGIProcessGroup django_app
```

urls.py of the site

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), #THIS PAGE WORKS
    path('projects/', include("projects.urls")),
    path('', include("blog.urls")),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

urls.py (blog)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name="home"), #THIS PAGE WORKS
    path("blog/", views.blog_index, name="blog_index"),
    path("blog/<int:pk>/", views.blog_detail, name="blog_detail"),
    path("blog/<category>/", views.blog_category, name="blog_category"),
]
```

error.log (var/log/apache2/error.log) I tried templates and personal_portfolio/templates

```
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.989828 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418] mod_wsgi (pid=10952): Target WSGI script '/home/saidb/rp-portfolio/personal_portfolio/wsgi.py' cannot be
loaded as Python module.
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.989898 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418] mod_wsgi (pid=10952): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/saidb/rp-portfolio/personal_portfo
lio/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990213 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990324 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]   File "/home/saidb/rp-portfolio/personal_portfolio/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990336 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990349 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]   File "/home/saidb/rp-portfolio/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_w
sgi_application
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990356 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990368 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]   File "/home/saidb/rp-portfolio/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990374 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990384 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]   File "/home/saidb/rp-portfolio/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _
_getattr__
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990390 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]     self._setup(name)
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990399 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]   File "/home/saidb/rp-portfolio/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _
setup
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990405 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990415 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]   File "/home/saidb/rp-portfolio/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in
__init__
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990420 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990430 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990436 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990446 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990456 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990466 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990476 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990486 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990520 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990531 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]   File "/home/saidb/rp-portfolio/personal_portfolio/settings.py", line 68, in <module>
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990536 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418]     'DIRS': [os.path(BASE_DIR, 'personal_portfolio/templates')],
[Sun Apr 14 09:20:34.990564 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10952:tid 140266601051904] [remote 5.51.50.121:63418] TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

views (blog_index)

```
def blog_index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_on')
    context = {
        "posts": posts,
    }
    return render(request, "blog_index.html", context)
```

THANK YOU FOR HELP !!

Comment: Can you show **views.blog_index** ?

Comment: yes of course, see above @VladimirGoncharuk

Comment: Can you remove `{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}` or some like `{% extends 'base.html' %}` from your **blog_index.html** or check that your base.html exists?

Comment: my base.html is in personal_portfolio -> templates -> base.html @VladimirGoncharuk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to create a `templates` folder at the project level and put the `base.html` file. And then in the `settings.py` file, update where Django looks for templates. Add `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')`. Let me know if that works for you.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: I updated my error.log above  (the path to base.html is personal_portfolio/templates/base.html) @joshlsulivan

Comment: @SaidBelhadj Awesome! Glad that worked for you! Now every app can inherit from `base.html`.